# IIS 7 and dynamic 404 error

Tags: iis-7, vbscript, asp

I have set a 404.asp page on my iis 7 yesterday and on this page beside some chacking i had at the end if anything was false i had:

```
response.status "404 Not Found"
response.AddHeader "location", domain & "/notfound"
```

it worked for an hour and then stoped working. on webs that checks the header status i get 404 not found and the addheader is there but no redirection is actualy happaning

what can i do to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that "domain" is defined previously in the script?

Any chance that you set this using IIS Manager and then did a code push which overwrote your web.config file?  If it worked for an hour, it seems like something was working at one point and that it's a later change that caused it to break.

Comment: i did it, went home, the day after i got email from the seo dep. telling me it stoped working any idea where to look in the iis?

Comment: Check to see if your settings are still in place.  If they aren't then you'll need to apply the changes again, and then make sure that your developers have the code updated in their source control too.